# Chai, cant test html element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, testing, chai

I am testing an angular project, and I first wrote the tests in Jasmine to test if an attribute of an html element exists or not like this and they work:

```html
 expect(element(by.css("*[id='ref_button']")).getAttribute('disabled')).toEqual(null);
```

Now I wanna try the same in Cucumber Chai.

And I do this:

```html
expect(element(by.css("*[id='ref_button']"))).to.have.attribute('disabled');
```

Th error that I get is ** Invalid Chai property: attribute**
Is there something I do wrong?

I have this in my package.json:

```html
 "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "chai-dom": "^1.8.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabled is a property not an attribute, infact in angular you can have

```
describe('test element', () => {
let something: DebugElement;

beforeEach(() => {
  something = fixture.debugElement.query(fn)
 });

 it('expect', () => {
  expect(something.properties.disabled).toBe(Boolean)
 });
});
```

this is how would you do it in Jasmine, I'm sure chai will have the same utility for obtaining the properties.

Comment: Thanks, but teh question is regarding Chai, It seems to work in jasmine